# Dynamic Pivot and Join

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table representing employees and their various details. I have another table representing training courses that employees have attended. Some employees have attended more courses than others. I need to represent each employee as a single row in a returned query with associated details and a column for each course they have been on.

Employee Table:

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
| EmpNum | EmpName | EmpType | EmpPhone |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
|   1234 | Smith   | FT      | 09876543 |
|   2345 | Jones   | PT      | 08765432 |
|   3456 | Brown   | FT      | 07654321 |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+
```

Skill Table:

```
+--------+------------+
| EmpNum | SkillName  |
+--------+------------+
|   1234 | First Aid  |
|   2345 | First Aid  |
|   3456 | First Aid  |
|   1234 | Safety     |
|   3456 | Safety     |
|   1234 | Leadership |
|   2345 | Leadership |
+--------+------------+
```

After joining these 2 tables, I'm looking to have the following returned:

```
+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
| EmpNum | EmpName | EmpType | EmpPhone |  Skill1   |   Skill2   |   Skill3   | Skill4 |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
|   1234 | Smith   | FT      | 09876543 | First Aid | Safety     | Leadership |        |
|   2345 | Jones   | PT      | 08765432 | First Aid | Leadership |            |        |
|   3456 | Brown   | FT      | 07654321 | First Aid | Safety     |            |        |
+--------+---------+---------+----------+-----------+------------+------------+--------+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're looking for is a dynamic crosstab. Read this [**article**](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Crosstab/65048/) by Jeff Moden for more information.

[**SQL Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d0f3c/1/0)

```
DECLARE @sql1 NVARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql2 NVARCHAR(2000) = '',
        @sql3 NVARCHAR(2000) = ''

DECLARE @range INT

--Added +1 here since you have extra Skill4 on your expected result
SELECT TOP 1 @range = COUNT(*) + 1 
FROM Skill GROUP BY EmpNum ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC

SELECT @sql1 =
'SELECT
    e.EmpNum
    , e.EmpName
    , e.EmpType
    , e.EmpPhone' + CHAR(10)

SELECT @sql2 = @sql2 +
'   , MAX(CASE WHEN rn = ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), rn) + ' THEN s.SkillName ELSE '''' END) AS ' 
    + QUOTENAME('Skill' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(3), rn))+ CHAR(10)
FROM(
    SELECT TOP (@range) 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
    FROM master..spt_values a
)t

SELECT @sql3 =
'FROM(
    SELECT *, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY EmpNum ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))
    FROM Skill
)s
INNER JOIN Employee e
    ON e.EmpNum = s.EmpNum
GROUP BY
    e.EmpNum, e.EmpName, e.EmpType, e.EmpPhone'

PRINT(@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
EXEC (@sql1 + @sql2 + @sql3)
```